# C++ - Accessing member functions from a map of object pointers, in a seperate class via getter functions

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, iterator

I'm fairly new to C++, I've tried to figure this out on my own but can't quite get there.

I've defined a map of pointers to a group of dynamically allocated objects in one class, with strings as the keys, along with two iterators (begin() and end()), and two getter functions corresponding to each iterator.

```
class a{

   std::map<string, Fruit*> fruitSalad;
   std::map<string, Fruit*>::iterator begin = fruitSalad.begin(), end = fruitSalad.end();

   std::map<string, Fruit*>::iterator getBeginIter() const; 
   std::map<string, Fruit*>::iterator getEndIter() const;

};
```

the objects referenced in the map, and their member functions need to be accessible in a separate driver class. To test my implementation I've been trying to print values from the objects with a for loop, by accessing the iterators via their accessors, as shown in the code below.

```
#include "a.h"

int main(){

   A fruitBowl;

   std::map<string, Object*>::iterator iter;

   for(iter = fruitBowl.getBeginIter(); iter != fruitBowl.getEndIter(); iter++){

      cout << iter.getName() << " " << iter.getQuantity() << endl;
   }
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
error: 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Fruit*>:: iterator' has no member named getName()

error: 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Fruit*>:: iterator' has no member named getQuantity()
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong with the assignment of the iterators in my driver class, but what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the live post preview to make sure your post is actually formatted properly before you hit "submit"?

Comment: I hope you don't use `a::begin` and `a::end`, as they will be initialized when the map is empty.

Comment: `iter->second->getName()`

Comment: As for your current problem, you might want to read [a good `std::map` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and its iterators, and iterators in general.

Comment: Hi @JoachimPileborg, What should I have put instead? I have edited the code to reflect the changes below, however nothing is being printed inside my for loop, so I would say you are right about the iterators being initalised when the map is empty.

Comment: Regarding the `a::begin` and `a::end` variables, don't have them at all, instead your `get` functions should use the `begin()` and `end()` functions of the map. With the variables, since you initialize them when the map is empty, both will be equal.

Comment: Regarding your errors after your update, the iterator will be a pointer-like structure to `std::map<...>::value_type`, which if you read [the `std::map` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg, I read the resource you posted a link to, and have read similar resources prior to posting the original question. Your comments helped get my on the right track to fixing the problem, I've posted the changes I made in my code in an update below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you write `iter = fruitBowl.getBeginIter();`,  `iter` is an iterator. This is a pointer-like object. If you want to access the method of the pointed-to object, you must first dereference it.

Second, the objects contained in the `std::map<foo, bar>` are `std::pair`s of `foo, bar`.

So the usage looks like

```
for(iter = fruitBowl.getBeginIter(); iter != fruitBowl.getEndIter(); iter++){
  auto pFruit = (*iter).second;

  cout << (*pFruit).getName() << " " 
       << (*pFruit).getQuantity() << endl;
}
```

The first dereference is to access the `value` of the key-value pair in the `map`;
the second one is to access the `Fruit` referenced by the pointer.

Or, using the  syntactic sugar for pointer manipulation:

```
for(iter = fruitBowl.getBeginIter(); iter != fruitBowl.getEndIter(); iter++){
 auto pFruit = iter->second;

  cout << pFruit->getName() << " " 
       << pFruit->getQuantity() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys, I appreciate your help.

Turns out it was a relatively simple problem and fix as most beginner programming errors are. I misinterpreted Joachim Pileborg's comment earlier in the thread- I was in fact using begin() and end() to start with, although this comment did set me on the right line of thinking.

The problem was that although I initialized the the iterators that I named 'begin' and 'end' with the iterators returned from the iterator funcitons begin() and end(), I was doing so immediately after I defined the map, before it had any values in it- as shown below.

```
std::map<string, Fruit*> fruitSalad;
std::map<string, Fruit*>::iterator begin = fruitSalad.begin(), end = fruitSalad.end();
```

So i guess this meant my iterators both pointed to the same memory location, so when I accessed these iterators via the getters in the driver class, the for loop would terminate just as soon as it would begin which is why no values were being printed even after fixing the original errors in my code as pointed out by mookid.

To remedy this I simply initialised the values of the pointers in class a inside the constructor, which is where the values of the map are read in from a file as shown below.

```
// class a constructor

a(){
    ...  // initialise some other variables
    loadFruitValues();  // reads values in from a .txt file to the map
    iter1 = fruitSalad.begin();  
    iter2 = fruitSalad.end();
}
```

Now when the code runs the iterators returned correctly point to the beginning and end of the map, allowing the for loop to iterate over the contents stored inside the map.

Thanks again for the replies, I'd still be stuck without all of your input. Both answers helped me equally but I think I can only site one as being the one that helped me the most. And my apologies for my original question not being formatted correctly, it's my first post- I'll try to make sure my next ones on point.